# Google Cloud Endpoints, hebrew get turned into question marks

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encoding, utf-8, google-cloud-endpoints

I have got this simple API written in java:

```
@Entity
class Bean
{
   @Id Long id; //auto-generated
   String name;
   // getters and setters
}

@Api(name = "myApi",
        version = "v1",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "helloworld.example.com",
                ownerName = "helloworld.example.com",
                packagePath=""))
public class MyAPI {
    public Slides update(Bean b) {
        OfyService.ofy().save().entity(b).now();
        return slides;
    }
}
```

when I execute this endpoint using the `api explorer` with this string `עברית` it saves it and returns `�����`

I have also checked using hardcoded values that this is not a problem with the saving mechanism, also it does this even when I log the value to the console instead of saving it.

Things I have tried:

- `<property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />` in
  `<system-properties>`
- a custom filter that sets `utf-8` on the
  request and response servlets

Comment: If you can [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Component=Endpoints) it would be helpful. Including an API Explorer link might be helpful in diagnosing the issue, as well.

Comment: Where do you see the ����� appear? It could be related to the browser or terminal and its handling of utf-8.